# Document Viewer issue

Tags: 14.04, pdf, evince

I have a pdf file without the '.pdf' extension in the name. When I try to open the file with 'Evince Document Viewer' I get 'Unable to open document "name" Error opening file: permission denied' - however, if I add the '.pdf' extension to the name I am able to open the document. I am sure I was able to open the file previously regardless of extension, does anyone know what may have caused this? Its Evince because Gimp can open the pdf regardless of extension.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the nature of `evince` and some have reported as a `bug`, see [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+question/140927) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1403717). Evince will not open files without the `.pdf` extension added to it. To get it to do so you have to add the `.pdf` file extension to any document, at least that's `evince` for now.

Comment: Thanks!  On the second link they mention that app armor may also have something to do with it, so I may check that out.  Good thing that it is not just me though.  Thanks!